# Try to understand relationship between line height and padding and height

Tags: css

All:

I am pretty new to CSS, could anyone give a little simple explanation how line-height/padding/height works together?

For example: if I want to define a DIV with `height:60px; padding:5px; font-size:12px;` then what should I use for `line-height` to make the text align center both vertical and horizontal, should I use 60-10 or 60 or something else and why?

```html
<div style="background-color:lightblue;height:60px; font-size:22px; padding:5px; line-height:60px;">
    test line-height
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [box model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), it should become clear quite easily: The height property defines the content height, padding will add space around the content (but within the object) so thatheight + padding-top + padding-bottom equals your total element height (not counting borders).

line-height simply defines how much vertical space a single line of text should occupy. Text will only render in the content area, so what you set your padding to doesn't matter for vertically centering with line-height.

That means all you have to do is **set your line-height equal to the height of your element** to achieve vertical centering of text (this only applies to non-wrapping text, and only if 12pt of your font isn't larger than 60px).
In your example, you'd have to set:

```
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
```

Horizontal centering has nothing to do with either declaration - all you have to do for that is to use:

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

line-height defines the vertical space bentween one line to another line below.

The higher it is the higher the vertical space bentween each line in that div.

If you want to make the text to be horizontally centered you put this in your DIV:

```
text-align: center;
```

To make it vertically centered you put this in your DIV:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```